# Sides from angles of a triangle

Tags: triangles

How does one find the side lengths of a right triangle in relation to each other using just the angles? I have all three angles. Is this even possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible. If you scale up your triangle by a constant factor in every side, by similarity the angles stay unchanged. However, the sides don't.

Comment: You will need one more item of information: the side opposite one of the (specified) angles, or area. In *spherical* geometry, by contrast, if you know the angles you know the sides, and vice-versa.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you point me to a good source about spherical geometry and your comment? As my intuition tells me, if I scale up the whole sphere, the angles stay unchanged but the sides don't. This means the sphere has a defined size? Wikipedia's page about the topic is practically useless.

Comment: The point is that in spherical geometry the sphere radius is fixed.  You are correct that if you scale up the sphere the sides scale as well, but given the sphere radius the angles give you the sides.  The point is that the radius of the sphere sets the scale, while in the plane there is nothing to set the scale.  A simple example is a spherical triangle with all angles $\frac \pi 2$.  The sides are then a quarter circumference, or the sphere radius times $\frac \pi 2$

Comment: This is for a fixed radius of sphere. The Wikipedia article on [spherical trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) is more relevant. Of course, this has nothing to do with your plane geometry question, where similarity definitely does not imply congruence.

Answer (score 1):

you can only get the ratios of the side lengths to one another... Not the actual lengths of the sides..

Comment: how does one get this ratio?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to get the *ratio* between the sides.  However, you can't get the actual lengths of the sides because [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29) triangles will have identical angles but different sides.

Comment: how would one go about this? Is it like the following: sin(a)*sin(c):sin(b)*sin(c)?

Comment: because when I do anything along those lines it does not work